# Finding where a string is in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I have a string for example
0010101101010101010101010111100010101010011010
and I have this string
111000
I want to find out where this string is in the string
for example, 111000 would be around 26 numbers in.

0010101101010101010101010111100010101010011010

-------------------------------------------111000

```
                         ^26
```

I would then take that 26 and do something with it

Do I need to do the string searching manually, by taking the first leter off and doing string.startswith(111000) or is there a way to find out like a built in method? regex perhaps? string builder?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your username is borderline offensive.

Comment: I thought it was funny

Comment: `string.IndexOf("yourstring")` is what you need to be looking for.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, and im sorry if my username is offensive, this will be my only question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string longString = "the stirng with zeros and ones";
string searchString = "111000";
int startIndex = longString.IndexOf(searchString);
```

If you apply this to your examples, startIndex will be 25 as it is zero based.

Comment: Is it possible to get a long back? I *might have to be(once I get more ram to)* dealing with MASSIVE strings of binary

Comment: Nope, as the maximum number of characters in a string is also the maximum number that can be represented with int32